# Why is there this exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, exact-sequence, deformation-theory

On page 49 in Hartshornes "Deformation Theory", in the proof of theorem 6.4 he states that the following exact sequence $0\to J\otimes O_{X}\to O_{X_{1}} \to O_{X}\to 0$ gives rise to an exact sequence of abelian groups $0\to J\otimes O_{X}\to O^*_{X_{1}} \to O^*_{X}\to 0$, so that the left group is just the additive group and the groups in the middle and on the right are the corresponding groups of units. I would like to know why is there this exact sequence, as well as when in general you can do something like this.

Setting: $X$ is a scheme flat over a local artin ring $C$. $C'$ is another local artin ring that surjects to $C$ with kernel $J$ (that has square 0). $X_{1}$ is an extension of $X$ over $C'$, that is: there is a closed imbedding $X\to X_{1}$ where $X_{1}$ is flat over $C'$ and it holds that $X=X'\times_{C'} C$.

Comment: The right hand map is obvious. For the left side map, if $s\in J\times O_{X_1}$, show that $1+s\in O_{X_1}$ is a unit, to get a map. Also, it factors through $J\otimes O_X$. Once you have the maps, check exactness locally.

Comment: Dear @Mohan,  at the risk of seeming indiscrete, may I ask you why you don't give complete answers to questions rather than  excellent but alas  very short comments? I'm asking for selfish reasons: I  learn a lot from your obvious expertise and I might not be the only user to wish for more detailed answers  from you.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you for your kind comment and I guess, terseness became second nature, since I felt, may be wrongly, that the hints made the OP work a bit, thereby making their understanding better. Mathematics is a hands-on subject, but I realize I am not doing what is expected and will try to make amends. Thank you once again.

Comment: Great, @Mohan: I'm looking forward to your answers! And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let me do this for rings, other case being similar. Let $A$ be any ring (commutative with identity) and $J\subset A$ an ideal with $J^2=0$. Then, I claim that there is an exact sequence $0\to J\to A^*\to (A/J)^*\to 0$ of abelian groups. The only observation is that if $j\in J$, $1+j$ is a unit in $A$, since $(1+j)(1-j)=1$.

The right side map is obvious and the left side map is $j\mapsto 1+j$. Since $1+(j+k)=(1+j)(1+k)$, we see that this indeed a map of abelian groups. Surjectivity on the right is clear, since any lift of a unit in $A/J$ is a unit in $A$. Exactness is clear too, since if $a\mapsto 1\in (A/J)^*$, this means $a=1+j$ with $j\in J$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even though I did conquer the question I asked about it eluded me that all one needs is that $J^2=0$. Thanks a lot!